# Azure Service Bus - Multiple namespaces Java

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azureservicebus

I have the following scenario:

- multiple microservices
- each microservice can send messages to any other microservice thought Azure Service Bus
- every user that is registered in the app has its own service bus

I'm developing the app using SpringBoot.
When sending a message, I managed to connect on runtime to a user namespaces using `@RequestScope` when creating `QueueClients` bean. The issue is that I don't know how to make all receivers to listen to all namespaces.

The only thing that I could find was a library for C#(https://docs.particular.net/samples/azure/custom-partitioning-asb/).

There is any possibility to do this in SpringBoot?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus does not have a feature that would support cross-namespace references. Your application would have to explicitly connect to all the namespaces and exchange the messages between those. That will mean opening separate clients/connections to the namespaces.

> every user that is registered in the app has its own service bus

This is not quite a typical use of the namespaces. I would suggest reviewing your design and/or technology use.

Comment: Is it typical use to have a Service Bus namespace per tenant in a multi-tenant system?  This could mean there are thousands of namespaces (depending on number of tenants).  How would you subscribe to all these queues across different namespaces?  Currently trying to create an Azure worker role which creates 1000 ServiceBusProcessor instances, but having doubts on this approach.

Comment: 1000s of namespaces is not economical in production. A single namespace can be used for multi-tenancy but the devil is in details.